# rename or re-alias builtin vim command to make completion unambiguous

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a vim plugin (Startify) whose name/command overlaps with the name of a builtin vim command, `:startinsert`, which I don't use. I would like to rename or in some way mask the builtin command (e.g. to `:UNUSEDstartinsert` or something), so that I can begin typing ":Startify" and press tab to complete the name, rather than having to type the entire string to disambiguate it from :startinsert.

Ways I tried to rename `:startinsert`:

- `:cabbrev`, `:cnoreabbrev` - correctly adds an alias but doesn't delete original command
- `:delcommand` (only operates on user commands)

How do I rename a builtin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, there is no way to delete or rename a built in Vim command. Vim won't even let us create all lowercase commands. We have to resort to tricks like `cabbrev` to create ["aliases"](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=746). The best advice is to come up with a different name or maybe a nicer alias.

Answer (score 1):

There is no ambiguity between `:startinsert` and `:Startify`; built-in commands are lowercase and custom ones start with an uppercase letter.

I assume you have `:set ignorecase`, and then Vim will offer both as completions for `:start`. Instead of relying on completion for correcting the case, just type enough (properly cased) characters to make the command unique. Depending on your configuration, this could be as short as `:S`, `:St`, `:Sta`, etc.